SQL Server schema restore
I have taken a backup of SQL Server DB with data in .bak file. Now I want to restore only schema of this db with another name. How to do this?
There is an option in PgAdim (PostgreSQL) to restore only schema even though you had a backup file with data.

I'm not answering (as I don't know if it's possible via a backup file), but as a suggestion you could script the schema (without data) via right-click -> tasks -> generate scripts

A backup is a backup of the entire database; you cannot RESTORE just the schema from it. If you want just the schema then you should get that from your database project. There are, also tools like DBCC CLONEDATABASE which creates schema-only & read-only copy of a database, however, it should be noted that recently Microsoft changed support on this tool to diagnostic purposes only and is not supported for use in a production environment
